# partition creation date?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, wmi

I need to write a c# function which takes a drive letter (like `C:\`) and tells me when the partition `C:\` was created (i.e. formatted).

Is there a way (via WMI, or via Win32, or via .NET) to obtain the date the filesystem was created?

Comment: Does Windows even record that information?

Comment: I hope so. Otherwise I need some similar info. My purpose is to create a unique partition id.

Comment: IIRC they used to just use the current date/time converted to the DOS format which ends up as an int.

Comment: and where can I read that int? that could be useful in the creation of a unique id. thanks

Comment: I don't recall tbh, not done anything like this for a long long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the WMI.
Take a look at
[Win32_DiskPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Maybe you can also use
[Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I had already checked there, but I don't see any property which helps. In win32_diskpartition I do see an "InstallDate" property, but the explanation is obscure: "Date the object was installed.". What object?